# IndexWriterConfig in Lucene

Tags: lucene

During IndexWriteConfig object creation codec is loaded into memory from the resource file

META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec

I wondered if there is a way to specify the codec and not ask it to load, and read the file at runtime. For performance and security reasons, we would like this to happen.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you have a `META-INF/services/org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec` file? That is not a standard Lucene thing. Are you using Lucene with some other library/tool/framework?

Comment: (You cannot create an `IndexWriteConfig` object without a codec. I suppose you could set it to null using `iwc.setCodec(null)` and then set it back to an actual valid codec again. But why? What "_performance and security reasons_" could there be for doing this? But again, maybe the question is missing some relevant context.)

Comment: I am running Lucene inside a restricted environment where I/O is not allowed. Since the code IndexWriterConfig performs a read on the resource file, the read fails. I would like to understand if there is a way for me to initiate IndexWriteConfig w/o this read on the config.

Comment: I think you may need to clarify that. If I/O is not allowed, then your program cannot be loaded into memory in the first place. What _specific_ I/O are you not allowed to do, that you want to do? Classloading `org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec` cannot be one of those things - can it? On the other hand, if you want to load a list of stopwords from a file (or something like that) then I can see what you might mean. But it's not clear from your question, or your comment.